# How to remove the back button, forward and Donе over the keyboard ios

Tags: xcode, cordova

I need to show when the keyboard does not have these buttons. How can they be removed?

Answer (score 3):

This question is tagged Cordova, so I assume you want to know how to do this in a hybrid app. The bar you are referencing is called the *Form Accessory Bar*. Follow the following to steps to disable this bar.

---

**1. Install keyboard plugin**

Since Cordova 3.2 there is a core plugin called 'Keyboard', make sure you install/enable this into your project. You can view the project here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard

To install type `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#master:keyboard` in your project folder.

---

**2.a Disable Form Accessory bar trough code**

After the app loads, you should call `Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true)` after the `deviceready` event has fired.

For example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){ 
     Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true);
});
```

---

**2.b Disable Form Accessory bar trough config.xml**

Alternatively there is a configuration option in your config.xml that allows you to disable the Accessory Bar for the whole application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Comment: 1. If you type cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#dev:keyboard produces an error Error: Command failed: error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

Comment: 2. Such an option in the new version Cordova is not supported

Comment: Just realised that the repo no longer has that branch, so just use `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#master:keyboard` instead, and yes that option is supported **as long as you install the plugin**.